# Laravel Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization

> Before you start giving vote-down or mark as duplicated please read:

I have read [Cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143651/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails) and it is not my case,

1. I have existing record
2. my table supports cascade on delete.
3. I also have my unsigned columns nullable

-- codes provided below

## Issue

I am trying save related data in 3rd table named `product_attributes` with `sync` method, which gets `product_id` and `attribute_id`

## Code

`schema`

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('product_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->integer('attribute_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        });
        Schema::table('product_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('attribute_id')->references('id')->on('attributes')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
}
```

`product model`

```
public function attributes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes', 'product_id', 'attribute_id');
}
```

`attribute model`

```
public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

`product controller`

```
$product->save()
$product->attributes()->sync($request->attributes, false);
```

`blade`

```
<select class="form-control" name="attributes[]" id="attributes" multiple="multiple">
  @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
    <option value="{{ $attribute->id }}">{{ $attribute->title }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

## Error

this is what I'm getting:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shopping`.`product_attributes`, CONSTRAINT `product_attributes_attribute_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `product_attributes` (`attribute_id`, `product_id`) values (*parameters, 3))
```

**Anyone can help with that?**

## Update

Here is what I get when I send my data to controller

[image: one]

Comment: Seems about right. Except for your `->products()` relationship, but that shouldn't matter in the code you posted. I'd double check the value of `$request->attributes` just before the sync: `dd($request->attributes)` Seems like it's "*parameters", which just seems weird

Comment: @devk exactly, when i dd request->attributes it gives me empty parameters but you see in my dd request->all() i have those values.

Comment: @mafortis try with `$request->get('attributes')`

Comment: @JinalSomaiya it's working now, thank you. But why isn't working in default code? the code i shared in my question I used in 4 applications before this is the first time i have to use it with get('')?!

Comment: @mafortis read this for more info. https://laraveldaily.com/differences-request-get-vs-request-input-vs-helper-vs-get_data/